# assigning a division dynamically to a set of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hide the 1st row and the next 3 rows using a span id which is a child of 1st row..

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div><span id="id_1">Sample</span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>row2</tr>
<tr>row3</tr>
<tr>row4</tr>
<tr>row5</tr>
```

when ever you click on sample ,need to hide row 2 row 3 and row 4 along with the parent row.

i tried using `$("#id_1").parent('tr').hide();` to hide the tr which contains span but its not working.

How can I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$("#id_1").closest('tr').hide();
$("#id_1").closest('tr').nextAll('tr').hide();
```

**[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/7x7Uz/)**

**or**

```
$("#id_1").parents('tr').hide();
$("#id_1").parents('tr').nextAll('tr').hide();
```

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/7x7Uz/1/)**

You can use it like

```
$("#id_1").closest('table').find('tr').hide();
```

**[Demo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/7x7Uz/2/)**

Read docs for  [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) and [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents) and [:not(:last)](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$('tr td span[id]').click(function(){
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    row.nextAll('tr').slice(0,3).add(row).hide();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MPE7g/).

References:

- [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/).